# Django: Deleting user selected entries from a database

Tags: django

I have a Django app that displays a list of rows in a table to the user. Each row maps to an entry in a database. I want to let the user select the rows they would like deleting by adding a checkbox to the end of each row and a delete button ( similar to how gmail lets you delete multiple mail messages). I can't quite figure out how to write the view in terms of finding out which rows were selected and how to map these to the IDs of the entries that need deleting from the database. A simple code snippet showing how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I've found this [code snippet](http://www.djangofoo.com/93/request-post-get-multiple-values) that I think should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CheckboxSelectMultiple](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple) widget to auto-generate the corresponding `HTML` code so you don't have to do it manually.

You can define your form like so:

```
class UsersForm(forms.Form):
    users = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=[QuerySetIterator(Users.objects.all(), "", False)], label="")
```

Another advantage is that you also get validation for free.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [formset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) and pass `can_delete = True` to the constructor. Then, in the template,

```
{{formset}}
```